# How to get information about LIBID rate?

Tags: interest-rate

I can find the information regarding LIBOR rate, for example like in this [link](https://www.macrotrends.net/2515/1-year-libor-rate-historical-chart), but I can't find anything about LIBID rate even though there are many sites providing the LIBID definition. Can anybody help me with the formula on how to derive LIBID rate or any site that provides LIBID rate?

Answer (score 1):

Per Investopedia ([here](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/09/difference-between-libid-libor.asp) and [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/libid.asp)):

> LIBID [...] has no formal correspondent responsible for fixing it.

and

> LIBID is not standardized or publicly available. It is not used outside of the interbank lending market.

Several references ([BlackRock](https://www.blackrock.com/cash/en-at/insight-and-education/glossary#l), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Interbank_Bid_Rate), and [Treasurers.org](https://wiki.treasurers.org/wiki/LIBID)) indicate that it is traditionally (and informally) treated as being LIBOR minus 0.125%. Although one of those (Wikipedia) indicates that as bid/offer spreads have tightened, the 0.125% estimate is not always appropriate.